# How to pass commandline arguments to csharp-shell

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

I try to call the csharp shell this way:

```
csharp proc.cs /storage
```

csharp error CS2007: Unrecognized command-line option: '/storage'

The 'man' file is unclear about options - they are shown in the parameters list, but never explained, man says:

```
csharp [--attach PID] [-e EXPRESSION] [file1 [file2]] [options]
```

Even if I use:

```
csharp proc.cs p1 p2 /storage
```

the error is the same. The leading slash is not accepted, even not, if it is escaped (which I explicitely wish to prevent me to do).
This looks like bad design.
Is there probably a workaround?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-csharp/), *"csharp is an interactive C# shell that allows the user to enter and evaluate C# statements and expressions from the command line."* It's not meant to compile and run a `.cs` file. Are you confusing it with `csc.exe`? Or am I looking at the wrong documentation?

Comment: Not absolutely sure - but what will a shell be, if it cannot execute a script?
From 'man':
Files specified in the command line will be loaded and executed as scripts.

Starting  with  Mono  2.10,  the  csharp command can be used as an interpreter executed by
executables flagged with the Unix execute attribute.   To do this, make the first line  of
your C# source code look like this:
"#!/usr/bin/csharp"
The latter should support my opinion ;-)
The behavior, I explained, is the same in both cases.

Comment: Yeah, but it also says, *"[.cs files] should only contain statements and expressions, they can not contain full class definitions (at least not as of Mono 2.0). Full class definitions should be compiled into dlls and stored in that directory."*. Given this, it's not clear to me what `/storage` is supposed to do in your case. The shell *executes commands*. It doesn't compile an executable. So your `.cs` file should only contain lines like `Console.WriteLine("Hello World");` or `int AnswerToLife = 42;`